# Is there a way of disable navigation on ngx-swiper-wrapper when there's only 1 slide?

Tags: typescript, slider, angular6, swiper.js

I have an app with multiple swipers, slides are generated dynamically by different servers.
I need to disable navigation and pagination (no bullets or swiper effect) if there's only 1 slide on the swiper.

I've done some google research and until now I've only found Jquery answers. I'm not allowed to use Jquery, only typescript.
 I've tried creating a condition with "document.querySelectorAll('.slider').length == 1" but it's not finding "slider" on DOM so always returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

So I was stuck with this for 2 days and finally found the answer, it was as simple as adding "watchOverflow: true" on the swiper config:

```
 public config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    slidesPerView: 1.16,
    spaceBetween: 4,
    centeredSlides: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    scrollbar: false,
    navigation: false,
    pagination: true,
    watchOverflow: true
  };
```